# Merge JSON String with Map using Jackson without deserializing the String

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

Let say I have a String `{"foo": "bar"}` and a Map `Map("hello" -> "world")`.

Using Jackson, how do I combine them into a String `{"foo": "bar", "hello": "world"}` **without** deserializing the foo-bar String first?

The foo-bar String comes from another system (trusted, will return valid JSON String), and it's inefficient to deserialize it into Map just to add a few properties, and then serializing it back to String.

Comment: I think that's the only way you can do this, Java can't understand the JSON until it has been parsed (valid or not). If you really don't want to parse it, you could serialize the map, remove the opening bracket, remove the closing bracket of the other one and concatenate them with a comma in the middle.

Comment: rather than doing string concatenation i will prefer deserializing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the end brace with a comma.
Produce the JSON string for your map.
Remove the start brace from your map JSON.
Concatinate the strings.

Comment: I was expecting something more elegant than this. Oh well... :)